# Are there any security issues to avoid when providing a either-email-or-username-can-act-as-username login system?

Tags: php, security, authentication

I am in the process of moving from a "username/password" system to one that uses email for login.  I don't think that there's any horrible problem with allowing either email or username for login, and I remember seeing sites that I consider somewhat respectable doing it as well, but I'd like to be aware of any major security flaws that I may be introducing.

More specifically, here is the pertinent function (the query_row function parameterizes the sql).

```
function authenticate($p_user, $p_pass) {
    $user        = (string)$p_user;
    $pass        = (string)$p_pass;
    $returnValue = false;

    if ($user != '' && $pass != '') {
        // Allow login via username or email.
        $sql = "SELECT account_id, account_identity, uname, player_id 
                FROM accounts 
                JOIN account_players ON account_id=_account_id 
                JOIN players ON player_id = _player_id 
                WHERE lower(account_identity) = lower(:login) 
                      OR lower(uname) = lower(:login) 
                      AND phash = crypt(:pass, phash)";
        $returnValue = query_row($sql, array(':login'=>$user, ':pass'=>$pass));

    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Notably, I have added the `WHERE lower(account_identity) = lower(:login) OR lower(uname) = lower(:login) ...etc` section to allow graceful backwards compatibility for users who won't be used to using their email for the login procedure.  I'm not completely sure that that `OR` is safe, though.  Are there some ways that I should tighten the security of the php code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after formatting your query, it become clear to me that your OR is unsafe.
Make it

```
WHERE (lower(account_identity) = lower(:login) OR lower(uname) = lower(:login)) 
      AND phash = crypt(:pass, phash)";
```

Note the parenthesis around OR clause.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the catch, I thought that I was making it too easy on myself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see any particular harm in doing both email/username pairs. At the end of the day, using the email as login is just like having a different username, nothing more nothing less. Just ask the users to provide a screen name, you don't want to show their email if they login with that.

As for your code, you should really do a `mysql_real_escape_string` or similar on `$user` to avoid SQL injection (unless the `query_row` function does that for you). You can also escape `$pass` although no injection is possible there, as it's going to be hashed.

As far as I know the `OR` statement does not pose any particular harm.

Comment: No, he shouldn't as he obviously uses a parametrized query

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: That's why I wrote *unless the query_row function does that for you*. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: parametrized queries do not escape anything

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I'm sorry I still don't understand. I never used parametrised queries can you be more explicit?

Comment: parametrized queries just separate data from the query, and send it to the database separately. so, data never being added to the query string and therefore don't need to be escaped.

Comment: More to say, escaping works only when combined with quotes. W/o quotes it is useless. So, you either to say "properly formatted" or add quoting to the escaping and some other rules too, like type casting for the numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry but he's not querying the DB with those parameter, he is using a custom `query_row` function and we don't really know what's going on in there. As far as I know it may just be substituting `:user` with the `$user` parameter (putting quotes around it) with a regexp without escaping anything. So I think my point is still valid.

Comment: I was using query_row to parameterize the sql inputs, yeah.